# Keep getting connection reset for every web resource when setting proxy in playwright (Java)

Tags: java, proxy, playwright

(I use chrome channel on chromium browser with headless mode turned off for testing)

I create a proxy options like that:

```
new Proxy("000.000.000.000:1080").setPassword("passwordhere").setUsername("usernamehere")
```

I also tried to do it like that

```
new Proxy("http://000.000.000.000:1080").setPassword("passwordhere").setUsername("usernamehere")
```

Currently, I am using a socks5 proxy which is shown to be working through different proxychecker websites and telegram options. But when I try to get anything inside the browser with this proxy - I get connection reset every time. What is the problem? I cant find anything related to it on the internet.